# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" happens in Java socket programming

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets

I'm learning to use socket in Java. I got this example online and tried to implement it.It is a game of guessing numbers. The server gets a random number for user to guess from client. I built this project in Eclipse 4.2.2. But when I tried to start server in terminal from MAC, it shows this:

```
ritekiMacBook-Pro:test Michael$ javac ServerApp.java
ServerApp.java:45: ?Ҳ???????
???ţ? ???? ClientApp
λ?ã? ?? test.ServerApp.ServerThread
                ClientApp.finished = true;
                ^
ServerApp.java:48: ?Ҳ???????
???ţ? ???? ClientApp
λ?ã? ?? test.ServerApp.ServerThread
                ClientApp.finished = false;
                ^
ServerApp.java:51: ?Ҳ???????
???ţ? ???? ClientApp
λ?ã? ?? test.ServerApp.ServerThread
                ClientApp.finished = false;
                ^
ServerApp.java:54: ?Ҳ???????
???ţ? ???? ClientApp
λ?ã? ?? test.ServerApp.ServerThread
              if (!ClientApp.finished){
                   ^
ServerApp.java:60: ?Ҳ???????
???ţ? ???? ClientApp
λ?ã? ?? test.ServerApp.ServerThread
            if (!ClientApp.finished){
                 ^
ServerApp.java:63: ?Ҳ???????
???ţ? ???? ClientApp
λ?ã? ?? test.ServerApp.ServerThread
            ClientApp.finished = true;
            ^
6 ????



ritekiMacBook-Pro:test Michael$ java ServerApp
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ServerApp
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ServerApp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

And this also happens to the ClientApp.java. 
I'm totally confused about this. I'm not sure its because the default language for my MAC is Chinese.

Here is the code for ServerApp and ClientApp:

ServerApp.java:

```
package test;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;

    public class ServerApp{
      static final int PORT = 9000;
      private ServerSocket serverSocket;
      private Socket socket;
      private BufferedReader netIn;
      private PrintWriter netOut;
      public ServerApp() throws IOException{
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        System.out.println("server start");
        while (true){
          // waiting for connect;
          socket = serverSocket.accept();
          ServerThread st = new ServerThread(socket);
          new Thread(st).start();
        }
      }
      class ServerThread implements Runnable{
        private Socket socket;
        private int randomNumber;
        private int clientGuessNumber;
        public ServerThread(Socket s) throws IOException{
          socket = s;
          netIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
          netOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        }
        public void run(){
          System.out.println("client" + socket.getInetAddress() + " is connect");
          randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
          System.out.println("random number is:" + randomNumber);
          try{
            clientGuessNumber = Integer.parseInt(netIn.readLine());
            System.out.println("client guess number is:" + clientGuessNumber);
            for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--){
              if (clientGuessNumber == randomNumber){
                netOut.println("OK, you got it right");
                ClientApp.finished = true;
              } else if (clientGuessNumber < randomNumber){
                netOut.println("Your number is smaller than it, you still have " + (i - 1) + "chances");
                ClientApp.finished = false;
              } else if (clientGuessNumber > randomNumber){
                netOut.println("Your number is bigger than it, you still have" + (i - 1) + "chances");
                ClientApp.finished = false;
              }
              netOut.flush();
              if (!ClientApp.finished){
                clientGuessNumber = Integer.parseInt(netIn.readLine());
              } else{
                break;
              }
            }
            if (!ClientApp.finished){
              netOut.println("OK, game over. You used all your chances.");
            }
            ClientApp.finished = true;
          } catch (IOException e){
          } finally{
            try{
              netOut.close();
              netIn.close();
              socket.close();
            } catch (IOException ee){
            }
          }
        }
      }
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        new ServerApp();
      }
    }
```

ClientApp.java:

```
package test;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ClientApp{
          private Socket socket;
          private BufferedReader netIn;
          private PrintWriter netOut;
          private BufferedReader keyboardIn;
          static Boolean finished = false;

          public ClientApp() throws IOException{
            System.out.println("Please input the server address, for local server please input localhost");
            keyboardIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            try{
              if (keyboardIn.readLine().equalsIgnoreCase("localhost")){
                socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), ServerApp.PORT);
              } else{
                socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(keyboardIn.readLine()), ServerApp.PORT);
              }
              System.out.println(ServerApp.PORT);
              netIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
              netOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            } catch (UnknownHostException e){
              System.err.println("cannot connect to server");
              System.exit(-1);
            }
            System.out.println("Connect suceeded");
            while (!finished){
              System.out.println("Please input a number between 0 and 100");
              netOut.println(keyboardIn.readLine());
//            netOut.print(keyboardIn.readLine());
              netOut.flush();
//            System.out.println(ServerApp.PORT);
              String str = netIn.readLine();
              if (str == null){
                finished = true;
                break;
              }
              System.out.println(str);
              if (str.startsWith("OK")){
                finished = true;
                break;
              }
            }
            netIn.close();
            netOut.close();
            keyboardIn.close();
            socket.close();
          }
          public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
            new ClientApp();
          }

}
```

Someone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: Check, if you are using the save version to compile and run you code.

Comment: Yes, they're both 1.6.0_65 version.

Comment: That compiler output is full of errors! What did you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the `java` command from inside the `test` folder.  Change to the parent directory and run `javac test/ServerApp.java` instead.

The Java compiler expects to find classes in directory structures that match the package structure.  Your `ClientApp` class is in the `test` package, so the compiler looks for it in a subfolder of the current directory named `test`.  You're running `javac` from the `test` folder, so the compiler looks for the class in a subfolder of `test` also named `test`.  This isn't where the `ClientApp` class is, so `javac` cannot find it.

When you change to the parent directory and run `javac` from there, both classes are then in a subfolder of the current directory named `test`, and the compiler can find them.

When I use the Java compiler to compile your code from the `test` folder, I get the following output:

```
C:\Users\Luke\Java\test>javac ServerApp.java
ServerApp.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
                ClientApp.finished = true;
                ^
  symbol:   variable ClientApp
  location: class ServerApp.ServerThread

  (5 similar errors omitted)
```

These are likely to be the same errors you are getting.

If I change to the parent directory and try again, your code compiles fine:

```
C:\Users\Luke\Java\test>cd ..

C:\Users\Luke\Java>javac test/ServerApp.java

C:\Users\Luke\Java>
```